# Not unique table/alias: table name

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

i get error Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'fixed_asset_reissue'

```
SELECT * FROM 
(`fixed_asset_reissue`, `fixed_asset_reissue`) 
RIGHT JOIN `fixed_asset_distribution` ON 
`fixed_asset_distribution`.`fixed_asset_list_id`=
`fixed_asset_reissue`.`fixed_asset_list_id` 
WHERE `customer` = 'R/00567/00'
```

the code is

```
$get2= $this->db->select('*')
           ->from('fixed_asset_reissue')
           ->join('fixed_asset_distribution','fixed_asset_distribution.fixed_asset_list_id=fixed_asset_reissue.fixed_asset_list_id','right')
            ->where('customer',$cust_id);
    $data['reissue']=$get1->get('fixed_asset_reissue')->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove this 'fixed_asset_reissue' form either get statment or from statment. This is the problem